# How to detect from which site user came to my site?

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

Suppose I have a website. User can come directly to my site and click on many hyperlinks just to hop from one page to another page in my site and again user can come to my site from another site like user can come to my site from Google search or another site.

My intention is that I have to detect user come from which to any page of my site from HTTP Module. Please guide me how to determine that user come from which to my site or directly accessing my site. Thanks

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer` should contain what you need, I believe it works also in handlers and modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see some sample code for retrieving the referrer on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)
eg:

```
Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
```

Mads Kristensen has blogged about his HttpModule that reads the refererrer on his [blog](http://madskristensen.net/post/HttpModule-to-block-external-referrers-in-ASPNET.aspx)

Comment: suppose user come to a page from another page of my site then Request.UrlReferrer refere my site page. basically i want to parmanently redirect with 301 status for those page which does not exist in my site now. google cache pages of my site what exist suppose few years ago. in this situation how could i parmanently redirect those page as a result google cache will update. so i want to parmanently redirect those pages request if user request that page from another site. please tell how to handle this sitauation from httphandler and routing feature. thanks